# Is it better to return a json object with relations or without?

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I know that it probably depends a lot on the situation but..
If I have like two different controllers. Cotroller A is a parent to controller B.

If call my end point `"/api/a/"`. It would return every A and each of their children.

Is it any efficent? Or would it be better to just returns all As from endpoint `"api/a"` without their children and make it seperately to get it from endpoint like `"api/b/[A's id]"`

I probably messed up a lot with this question.

But maybe someone could give me some kind of direction which should I follow @_ @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer really depends.  How often will A include data from B?  How large is B?

If the answer is that A will need data B almost all the time, and that B is not very large then I probably wouldn't have a controller for B at all.  In every request to A I would include and return B with it.

If the answer is A will almost never need B, and B is fairly large then in my A object I would include a BUrl property that has the url to B and then when I desire B I can go get it.

Finally another option would be to just have an optional parameter that will include B on request. ?includeb=true

It really depends on the situation.  I favor fewer controllers and including data where practical.  It's less maintenance and overhead.

Comment: How would you include the url in property? And thanks for answer ;3